# Load any libraries form any location after export

Tags: java, jar, libraries

is it possible to load additional libraries after the jar has been created?
I want to search a folder for jar-files, and load them as libraries. "They" will extend a class, I already have, so that I can adress them. The folder, of the libs is not the same as the folder, where the jar-file, that loads all the others is located. If there is no other way, than to change a settingsfile(where the libraries-to-be-loaded are linked) withinin the jar itself, that would be not great but helpful, too;)

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You just have to use URLClassLoader.

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("jar:file:/home/myapp/plugins/dateplugin.jar!/")}, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
MyInterface pluginClass = (MyInterface )loader.loadClass("com.mypackage.MyClass").newinstance();
```

[URLClassLoader Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)

You want to make sure you connect your classloader with the main one by passing the system classloader to the constructor. This will allow you to assign your newly loaded library to an existing interface. This is how you can make a plugin system for your game or application.

Here is a link to source code showing this in action: [Git Hub Repository for Sticky](https://github.com/markbernard/sticky). Look at the class sticky.gui.Main. It shows the plugin system loading new libraries after it has already started running.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for ;)

Comment: @0815Creeper No problem. Please mark the answer as accepted. Also I have some code that does this that I am going to put on GitHub so look back later and I will add the link.